# Incorrect timestamp in phpmyadmin db

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, timestamp, wamp

The timestamp in my db is off from what i have inputted.

In my php function, I have a sql query that inserts into a table with values including the timestamp. The hour part of the timestamp in the phpmyadmin db is off. Sometimes it's 4 hours, sometimes 5.

```
function fun ($pdo, $val, $time){
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table (col1, inputtime) VALUES($val, '$time')");
    $stmt->execute;
}
```

Is this a php, mysql, or wamp problem?

utc_timestamp is 5 hours ahead.

Comment: whats your timezone set to?

Comment: *Is this a php, mysql, or wamp problem?* - My guess would be a user problem which nobody is going to be able to help with, without seeing some code.

Comment: Please issue the command `SELECT @@time_zone, NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP()` and edit your question to tell us the result. This will reveal your MySQL server's timezone settings.

Comment: the time zone is correct. when i select now(), it's the correct time. my code is just a simple sql query thats executed in php.

Comment: @marvelownz show us the code!

Comment: Execute `DESCRIBE {your_table_name}` in PHPMyAdmin, do a screengrab and show us the structure of the table - also, the code where `$time` is being generated.

Comment: the structure is:
col1, varchar(225), NO. 
time, timestamp,NO, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

$time is inputted into the function.